# Maven release plugin error on mvn release:prepare

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, sonatype

I am using Maven 3.3.3 and Github SCM to release a jar to Sonatype.
I am able to run

```
mvn clean deploy -Dgpg.passphrase=xxxxxx
mvn release:clean -Dgpg.passphrase=xxxxxx
```

But on running 'mvn release:prepare -Dgpg.passphrase=xxxxxx' I am getting a maven-release-plugin error with the following error message

```
2015-08-21 00:20:52,839 ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project symphony: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project symphony: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862) [maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286) [maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197) [maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:290) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208) ~[maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:91) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.simulate(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:57) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:228) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286) ~[na:na]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.ForkedMavenExecutor.executeGoals(ForkedMavenExecutor.java:151) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:114) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:85) ~[na:na]
... 30 common frames omitted
```

Following are the relevant sections of the pom file

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:eveningsamurai/symphony.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:eveningsamurai/symphony.git</developerConnection>
    <url>git@github.com:eveningsamurai/symphony.git</url>
</scm>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<distributionManagement>
 <snapshotRepository>
   <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
 </snapshotRepository>
 <repository>
   <id>nexus-releases</id>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
 </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>v0.1</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
....
</build>
```

I have done the requisite Google + SO search but found nothing useful. I feel like there is a version mismatch somewhere but unable to figure out. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to share more output from maven

Comment: @avinash can you try to re-run the maven command with `-X` flag and see whether there is a stacktrace or not?

Comment: updated to include the complete stack trace

Comment: Usually somewhere above the generic Maven stacktrace that only says "I failed", there is an error message in plain English that vaguely explains what is actually wrong. It can be hard to spot since Maven plugins dump quite a bit of blurp.

Comment: @Gimby The only error message I see is "org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project symphony: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' "

Comment: I know it is frustrating to get errors that tell you nothing, but they tell nothing to people you are asking for help too. There are many steps involved in the release process and multiple systems. I would at least verify that all those urls are accessible; one thing that I find a little odd for example, is that in your distribution management I see two urls to the same system; one (snapshots) is **https**, the other (releases) is **http**. Is that really correct?

Comment: @Gimby Thanks you for your patience. You are right, I fixed that. However does not seem to help my cause. I still face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue with using the -X option in the command line. It was complaining about "Cannot obtain passphrase in batch mode". I was able to fix it by moving the signing process in the pom within a profile and activating the profile only for the deploy goal.